# jQuery: Select all elements with a given class, return their product (multiplication result)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unknown number of values (coming from server-side code) which are contained in spans with the class `num`.  I simply need to get the product of all of these values.

I tried `alert(multiply(jQuery('.num').val());` but no luck.  I know it's something simple, but I cannot wrap my head around it.  What am I missing?

Comment: u need to use '.num' instead of '.num.' notice the extra '.' at the end. its not required.

Comment: That was just a typo in the text

Comment: oh. can you share the html and the code for multiply method?

Comment: `.val()` returns only the value from the first selected element, not all values.

Comment: `.val()` is for form elements, you have span so need to use `.html()` or `.text()`, and you have a collection so need a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple procedural version could be

```
var result = 1;
$('.num').each(function() { result *= parseFloat($(this).text()); });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a for each and just sum the values.

```
var result = 0;      
$( ".num" ).each(function( index ) {
  var num = parseInt($( this ).text());
  result = result + num;
});

$('.result').text(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mo2f3na4/

**EDIT**

Multiplying was asked. Then set the result on default to 1 and replace

```
result = result + num;
```

with

```
result *= num;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mo2f3na4/1/

Comment: The result ought to show the product, so `result *= num;` would be correct here. And since we're multiplying, the result variable should be declared with the value of 1.

Comment: oh, you are right, not summing but multiplying was asked...overviewed this